# Apache camel jms queue REconsuming

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

Theoretical question. Working with JMS and Apache Camel asynchronously.

Is it possible create solution like:

1. Consumer consumes message `A` from `first.queue` queue
2. Message `A` is still in `first.queue` queue

   - Consumer do some logical action `X` with received message `A`, and finished with error(s). In this case, I want to schedule the same operation — receive message `A` from `first.queue` and do action `X` again
   - If action `X` finishes successfully, then remove message `A` from queue and finish the job

**In other words, I want to keep message `A` in queue `first.queue`, till action `X` is finished without errors. When its done - remove message from queue.**

Comment: I think you describing transactional behaviour. Try to set transacted=true to your jms-consumer.

Comment: Thank for this hint. Just red about transactional approach here http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/transactional-client.html  Maybe someone can share some example of this approach?